# Removing a pandas column with a unicode name

Tags: python, unicode, pandas

**edit:** the problem isn't unicode related

I have columns with unicode names, eg "#前田敦子:Japan". I'd like to remove these from my dataframe, but I'm getting a `UnicodeEncodeError`:

This code

```
for title_loc in f_df.columns:
    if 'Japan' in title_loc:
        f_df.drop(title_loc)
```

gives this error

```
  File "timeseries/sum_japan_timeseries.py", line 25, in read_timeseries_dir
    f_df.drop(title_loc)
  File "/home/isl/rfcompton/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1401, in drop
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels)
  File "/home/isl/rfcompton/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1623, in drop
    raise ValueError('labels %s not contained in axis' % labels[mask])
  File "/usr/local/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1379, in array_str
    return array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small, ' ', "", str)
  File "/usr/local/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 309, in array2string
    separator, prefix)
  File "/usr/local/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 230, in _array2string
    _summaryEdgeItems, summary_insert)[:-1]
  File "/usr/local/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 355, in _formatArray
    word = format_function(a[-1])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I can `.drop` just fine when the column name has no unicode, any ideas?

Comment: There are a few problems here.  `drop` by default operates on rows, not columns.  Also, by default it returns a new object and doesn't modify the original.  Are you sure the problem isn't due to it trying to print out the remaining columns, some of which also contain undisplayable Unicode?

Comment: ugh, yes you are right. The change to f_df.drop(title_loc, 1) fixes this. You can leave an answer (else I'll just delete this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here. `drop` by default operates on rows, not columns. Also, by default it returns a new object and doesn't modify the original. The problem may be due to it trying to print out the remaining columns, some of which also contain undisplayable Unicode.